# automatic inference of parametric types

Tags: julia

I am using the code below and it seems Julia should be able to infer the type parameters by itself, however this is not the case. Any ideas, maybe I'm doing something wrong?

```
abstract type ABS{A,B} end

struct MyStruct{A,B,K<:ABS{A,B}}
    a::A
    b::B
    MyStruct{A,B,K}(a::A,b::B) where {A,B,K<:ABS{A,B}} = new(a,b)
end

MyStruct{Int64,Float64,ABS{Int64,Float64}}(1,2.1) # <<-- works
MyStruct(1,2.1) # <<-- doesn't work
```

Comment: that's nothing to do with type inference, you just forgot to define a proper outer constructor, see [this doc section](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/constructors/#Parametric-Constructors-1).

Comment: How would you expect that to work? `K` is not defined from `a` and `b`. There are infinitely many possibilities that it can choose that it could potentially choose that would be correct (anything that's a subset of the abstract type `ABS{A,B}`) if other codes adding concrete subtypes of `ABS`.

Comment: @Gnimuc you are right. I made it work!

Answer (score 1):

I forgot the outer constructor, as @gnimuc pointed out. This code works:

```
abstract type ABS{A,B} end
struct Myk <: ABS{Int64,Float64} end

struct MyStruct{A,B,K<:ABS{A,B}}
    a::A
    b::B
    MyStruct{A,B,K}(a::A,b::B) where {A,B,K<:ABS{A,B}}= new(a,b)
end
# this is the outer constructor:
MyStruct(a::A, b::B, ::K) where {A,B,K<:ABS{A,B}} = MyStruct{A,B,K}(a,b)

# now this works:
MyStruct(1,2.1,Myk())
```